# Roots for a cubic equations

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Find all real or complex solutions of the simultaneous equations 
$$\begin{aligned}x+y+z&=3\\x^2+y^2+z^2&=3\\x^3+y^3+z^3&=\end{aligned}$$
I assumed that $x,y,z$ are 3 roots for a cubic equation such that $$W^3+aW^2+bW+c=0$$
and using relationship between roots of a polynomial equation I got $a=-3,\; b=3,\; c=-1.$
Which means the normal cubic equation is $（W-1)^3.$
My question is: are there possible complex solutions for such the relationship between $x,y$ and $z$ still be true. And please help me find the complex solutions as well. 
Thank you

Comment: what is with the third term?

Comment: The cubic equation is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The cubic equation is incomplete - I assume that you left out equal to $3$ on the RHS in the last equation. In that case it is easy to see that the only solution is given by $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$. If you meant the equations $x+y+z=x^2+y^2+z^2=3$ and $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$, then there are more interesting solutions, i.e., $x=\frac{\sqrt{-3}+3}{2}$, $y=\frac{-\sqrt{-3}+3}{2}$ and $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint: }$ Try the method of [Newton's Sums](https://brilliant.org/wiki/newtons-identities/).$$$$
Let $$P_i=x_1^i+x_2^i+x_3^i$$

Assuming that the given equations are $$x_1+x_2+x_3=3, x_1^2+_2^2+x_3^2=3, x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=k,$$

Let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ have roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$$$$$ We want to find the values of $a,b,c,d$ so as to find the roots of $f(x)$. This will furnish us with the values of $x_1,x_2,x_3$. $$$$
Also, $$ e_1  = \sum x_i  = - \frac{b}{a} $$ 
$$e_2 = \sum x_i x_j  = \frac{ c } { a} $$ 
$$e_3  = \sum x_i x_j x_k = - \frac{ d } { a} 
$$ $$$$
Lastly, the recurrence relation for $P_i$ for a polynomial of degree $k$ is as follows:$$$$

For $ i \leq k - 1 $, we have the formulas

$$P_1  = e_1 \times 1  $$
$$P_2 = e_1 P_1 - e_2 \times 2 $$
$$P_3  = e_1 P_2 - e_2 P_1 + e_3 \times 3 $$
$$$$

Since $P_1=3, P_2=3, P_3=k,$ we can calculate the corresponding values of $e_1, e_2, e_3$. This will give us the values of the coefficients $a, b, c,d$ of $f(x)$. It then becomes a simple task of factorizing $f(x)$ to find the values of its roots.

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy Schwarz Inequality

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)(1^2+1^2+1^2)\geq (x+y+z)^2$$

equality hold when $\displaystyle x=y=z$

So we have $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$.